# qemu-system-arm chroot illegal instruction

Tags: arm, router, qemu, firmware, chroot

I install qemu-system-arm in Ubuntu 16.04 to run firmware of dlink DIR868L. But when I use the command `chroot ./squashfs-root/ /bin/sh`, it just shows `Illegal instruction`. I get `squashfs-root/`from `DIR868LB1_FW203b01.bin` by `binwalk` and I am sure that `/bin/sh` exists in `squashfs-root/`.

I start `qemu` by `sudo qemu-system-arm -M versatilepb -kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-versatile -initrd initrd.img-2.6.32-5-versatile -hda debian_squeeze_armel_standard.qcow2 -append "root=/dev/sda1" -net nic -net tap` and use `scp` to cpoy `squashfs-root/` into virtual mechine. And I met the same problem when using `debian_wheezy_armel_standard.qcow2`

What should I do ? It has bothered me for the whole afternoon.

Or can anyone give me an example to run the ***arm*** firmware in qemu ? I only find lots of examples using firmware based on mips.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly because whatever CPU is in the DIR868lL is newer than the ARM926 CPU that the "versatilepb" board has. If the binaries from that firmware are built to use newer instructions, then running them in an emulation of an older CPU will result in an 'illegal instruction' signal, just as if you'd run them on real older ARM hardware.

This is similar to taking binaries that were built for a Core2 Duo and trying to run them on your old Pentium system: it won't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I try armhf using cortex-a9 which is used by DIR868L, it works perfect ! Thank you again ! HERE is the reference https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armhf/ for anyone meet the same problem as me.